# Generate and open PDF in new browser at clients machine with java IText

Tags: java, servlets, itext

I am trying to write in an existing pdf file and want to open it in new browser at clients machine. I saw many post related this and i tried all answers but still i am not getting result. File can be generated on my disk but i want to open it at new window once created.

**Code** :

```
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");         
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("Challan.pdf");
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(is, null);
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, baos);                  
        for(int i=1; i<= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++){    
              Phrase Namephrase = new Phrase("John Smith"); 
              Phrase Idphrase =  new Phrase("DPG10001");
              Phrase Datephrase = new Phrase("11/10/1980");
              PdfContentByte pdfcontent = pdfStamper.getUnderContent(i);            
              pdfcontent.beginText();
              ColumnText.showTextAligned(pdfcontent, Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL, Idphrase, 500, 428, 0); /*Do not change this values*/
              ColumnText.showTextAligned(pdfcontent, Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED, Namephrase, 500, 407, 0);     
              ColumnText.showTextAligned(pdfcontent, Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED, Datephrase, 500, 386, 0);
              pdfcontent.endText();            
        }           
         pdfStamper.close();
         pdfReader.close();
         // write ByteArrayOutputStream to the ServletOutputStream
         response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=ChallanStamped.pdf");
         // the contentlength
         response.setContentLength(baos.size());
         ServletOutputStream  sos = response.getOutputStream();                
         baos.writeTo(sos);            
         sos.flush();
         sos.close();
```

In this i am trying to read challan.pdf and want to update file and create new one.From jsp i am calling this servlet.
Please help me.

Update:
I tried with some changes but  still not working. My updated code is

```
`       ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("Challan.pdf"));
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(is, null);
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, baos);                  
      -----------Some Code -------------
         pdfStamper.close();
         pdfReader.close();

         response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=ChallanStamped.pdf");     
         response.setContentLength(baos.size());
          output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());                   
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
           int length;         
           while ((length = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {                 
                    output.write(buffer, 0, length);               
                }  

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
```

I am calling servlet from jsp through Ajax(sending lot of data).
And also i am getting java.io.IOException: Stream closed exception with this updated code.

Comment: Will that new pdf be stored **on disk** or **in memory only**?

Comment: @Jan it will be stored on clients machine disk.

Answer (score 0):

In order to open the pdf file in new window you need to do some changes in your jsp form.

```
<form action="yourServletURLPattern" method="post" target="_blank">
 -- Some Fields--
 -- Submit Button--
</form>
```

`target=_blank` will do the needful.

Now coming to your servlet code :

```
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

   ---------- Some Code in between-----------------------

   ServletOutputStream  sos = response.getOutputStream();                
   baos.writeTo(sos);
```

But this do nothing since your `ByteArrayOutputStream` Object contains nothing so what will you write to `ServletOutputStream`

I will not write code for you but can guide, So that you can achieve it yourself

1. Read File after editing using `BufferedInputStream`
2. Write it on OutputStream of Response using `BufferedOutputStream` (Simply Loop
   through the file)
3. Flush the Response's Output Stream

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried that way too but still it is not working.